# adding externel link for element in SiteMap using SiteMapNode object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom class implementation for sitemap which adds URL from database. However, I am only able to add relative paths. i.e. I am not able to add external links.

I've tried to use `some_node.URL property` to overwrite the URL and but it appends after the relative path.

For e.g. I am under domain `yahoo.co.in/some_link` and wants to go to `Google.com`. Sitemap produces a link like yahoo.co.in/some_link/Google.com.instead of only Google.com.

when I looked on internet there are some articles that says it adds relative path and somewhere i have also found the use of url property as well but when i actually implemented it is not working for me.